# Help with solving this DC circuit

Tags: dc

[image: DC Circuit. Solve for Vo[![][1]]][2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4az17.jpg)

I tried KVL, KCL and the standard stuff (My knowledge goes up to Super-nodes and Super-mesh) but I have no clue what the 4V source is actually supposed to do? Sorry if the answer is obvious, but I'm stuck on this.

Edit: I've added some labels and added an image of what I came up with.

Comment: When adding your new image, you removed the old one; also, you didn't even label *all* resistors, nor did you label your voltage sources.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It really just adds 4V of potential difference. What else should it do? No current can flow.

Comment: but the 0.5k Ohm resistance in series with 4V source doesn't change that potential drop?

Comment: to repeat: No current is flowing. If 0A current flows through a resistor, it has 0V voltage drop. Basics!

Answer (score 1):

Since the 4 V branch is open circuit no current is flowing. Therefore there is no voltage drop across its resistor. That means that the voltage at V- will be 4 V higher than on the right vertical wire.

You circuit is difficult to discuss because you haven't given component designations R1, R2, etc.